# Does a standard algorithm for sorting and partitioning two ranges in the following way exist?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I wonder whether a standard approach for the following algorithm exists. I want to sort and partition two ranges `x` and `y`. Both `x` and `y` should be partitioned using a binary predicate that takes an element from `x` and `y`.   The signature of the function would be something along the lines of:

```
template<typename ForwardIt1, typename ForwardIt2, typename Compare, typename BinaryPredicate>
std::pair<ForwardIt1, ForwardIt2> sort_and_partition(ForwardIt1 first1, ForwardIt1 last1, ForwardIt2 first2, ForwardIt2 last2, Compare comp, BinaryPredicate p);
```

Here `comp` is forwarded to `std::sort`. The binary predicate `p` is used for the partitioning. Then, for example:

```
std::vector<T> x;
std::vector<T> y;

auto [xm, ym] = sort_and_partition(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), std::less<T>{}, std::equal_to<T>{});
```

This would result in four ranges:

- x1: `[x.begin(), xm)`
- x2: `[xm, x.end())`
- y1: `[y.begin(), ym)`
- y2: `[ym, y.end())`

Where both `x1` and `y1` are sorted and contain equivalent elements (according to the binary predicate `p`). Effectively `x1` and `y1` contain the sorted intersection for `x` and `y` in the example. `x2` and `y2` are sorted as well, and contain all elements unique to `x` and `y` respectively.

Am I missing an obvious approach to implement such an algorithm by combining existing algorithms in the STL? I am planning now to write a custom implementation for this but wanted to check here first before starting on the implementation. What would be a good name for this algorithm?

*Update*, I've implemented the following algorithm that satisfies my requirements. The algorithm requires that the input ranges are sorted.

```
/// Takes two sorted input ranges, and partitions both ranges such that all
/// elements that occur in both ranges precede those elements that only occur in
/// one of the two ranges.
template<typename ForwardIt1, typename ForwardIt2, typename Compare>
std::pair<ForwardIt1, ForwardIt2> frc::binary_partition(
    ForwardIt1 first1, ForwardIt1 last1, ForwardIt2 first2, ForwardIt2 last2, Compare comp)
{
  auto equals = [&](const auto& x, const auto& y) { return !comp(x, y) && !comp(y, x); };

  // Invariant: first1 and last1 point to the first mismatch.
  std::tie(first1, first2) = std::mismatch(first1, last1, first2, last2, equals);

  while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
  {
    // Iterators to the next matching elements.
    auto fm1{first1};
    auto fm2{first2};

    // Find next matching elements in both ranges.
    while (comp(*fm1, *fm2) || comp(*fm2, *fm1))
    {
      if (comp(*fm1, *fm2))
      {
        ++fm1;
      }
      else
      {
        ++fm2;
      }

      if (fm1 == last1 || fm2 == last2)
      {
        return std::pair(first1, first2);
      }
    }

    // Find the end of the matching subsequence.
    auto [lm1, lm2] = std::mismatch(fm1 + 1, last1, fm2 + 1, last2, equals);

    // In case matching elements are found, move the mismatching subrange behind
    // the matching subrange.
    first1 = std::rotate(first1, fm1, lm1);
    first2 = std::rotate(first2, fm2, lm2);
  }

  return std::pair(first1, first2);
}
```

Comment: why don't you zip together these ranges and do desired operations?

Comment: Are there any constraints on `p` beyond *BinaryPredicate*? This would be quite easy for the case where `p` is the [equiv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) corresponding to `comp`. Otherwise which pairs of elements do you pass to `p`?

Comment: @Caleth, no additional constraints on `p`. Normally `p` would indeed be equivalence corresponding to `comp`.

Comment: As an example, would you expect `{xa, xb} {} {ya, yb} {}` in the case where `p(xa, yb) && p(xb, ya) && !p(xa, ya) && !p(xb, yb) && comp(xa, xb) && comp(ya, yb)`?

Comment: `{xa, xb} {} {ya, yb} {}` would be expected in the case where `p(xa, ya)`, and `p(xb, yb)`, and `comp(xa, xb)` and `comp(ya, yb)`. For example:  `{0, 1, 3, 5, 6}` and `{0, 2, 3, 6}` will result in `{0, 3, 6} {1, 5} {0, 3, 6} {2}`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `comp(xa, xb) && comp(yb, ya)`. There isn't an example in `int` that springs to mind, but consider `struct ColourInt { int value; Colour colour; }; bool comp(ColourInt lhs, ColourInt rhs) { return lhs.value < rhs.value; } bool equiv(ColourInt lhs, ColourInt rhs) { return lhs.colour == rhs.colour; }`, when partitioning `{ { 1, Red }, { 2, Blue } } { { 2, Red } { 1, Blue } }`

Comment: If I am understanding the problem correctly, this can be solved using sets.

You get the intersection of both sets, then get the set difference of both sets and the intersection, then sort all 3 sets.

Comment: @Makogan `std::set` is already sorted.

Comment: @Caleth is it still sorted after removing arbitrary elements? That sounds like inefficient implementation

Comment: @Makogan Neither `set_intersection` nor `set_difference` remove elements. They *copy* into a destination. And `set` is *always* sorted. It's generally implemented as a self balancing tree

Answer (score 0):

No, and I can think of two reasons:

1. You're actually demanding two algorithms: `std::sort` and `std::stable_partition` (or `std::partition` and `std::sort` of both partitions of each range). You can compose that yourself.
2. Algorithms implement their semantics in terms of **iterators** - that's where the extra part to make it work with two ranges should be implemented. In other words, if an algorithm's semantics can be defined with one input range, there won't be overloads for multiple ones.

   You have to use a custom iterator, which will internally manipulate two iterators of distinct ranges (containers). I think [`boost::zip_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in STL as far as I know.

Maybe what you could do is make use of the following functions provided by STL:

- sort x
- sort y
- use [mismatch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/?kw=mismatch) on x and y with a binary predicate

It returns a pair of iterators pointing to the first unmatched element of both sequences.

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class BinaryPredicate>
  pair<InputIterator1, InputIterator2>
    mismatch (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
              InputIterator2 first2, BinaryPredicate pred);
```

Comment: Yes, that would be my approach, but it requires possibly more than one call to `std::mismatch` and `std::rotate`.

Comment: Can you explain why several calls to `mismatch`? And why `rotate`?

Comment: Because `std::mismatch` only returns the first mismatch, there might be more. For example: `v = {0, 1, 3, 5, 6}`, `w = {0, 2, 3, 4, 6}`. In this there are multiple mismatches. The `std::rotate` would be used to implement the partitioning (by moving a mismatch to the 'end') assuming both ranges are initially sorted. The desired end result would be: `v = {0, 3,  6, 1, 5}` and `w = {0, 3, 6, 2, 4}`, returning `std::pair(v.begin() + 3, w.begin() + 3)`.

Comment: I see. I now understand your need I believe. You basically want to partition by the highest common value according to a binary predicate (taking into account if element is in both containers or not), and sort each of the partitions. Did I understand that the right way ? Also I suggest to show the example in the original question for clarity, it may make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where we can synthesize `p` from `comp`, this is roughly

```
template<typename ForwardIt1, typename ForwardIt2, typename Compare>
std::pair<ForwardIt1, ForwardIt2> sort_and_partition(ForwardIt1 first1, ForwardIt1 last1, ForwardIt2 first2, ForwardIt2 last2, Compare comp)
{
    // We don't strictly need copies of the two ranges, but it makes things easier. 
    // We do want them sorted, using an ordered set here gives that for free
    std::multiset<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt1>::value_type, Compare> set1{ first1, last1, comp };
    std::multiset<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt2>::value_type, Compare> set2{ first2, last2, comp };

    // Copy back into a partitioned [first1, last1)
    auto mid1 = std::set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), first1, comp);
    std::set_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), mid1, comp);

    // Copy back into a partitioned [first2, last2)
    auto mid2 = std::set_intersection(set2.begin(), set2.end(), set1.begin(), set1.end(), first2, comp);
    std::set_difference(set2.begin(), set2.end(), set1.begin(), set1.end(), mid2, comp);

    // And return our midpoints
    return { mid1, mid2 };
}
```

In the more general case, you will need to decide how many pairs of elements to compare in the partition step, as different choices will lead to different outcomes.